# Whats the truth on Shell Extensions in .NET?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, shell, com

Over the past couple of days, I have been researching how to write a shell extension so that I can create dynamic custom context menu entries and file decorations for my application and I am reasonably confused over the conflicting opinions of using .NET (managed code) to create a shell extension.

On one hand you have the camp of people who say that using managed code to create a shell extension is dangerous and discouraged (even after .NET 4.0):
[Now that version 4 of the .NET Framework supports in-process side-by-side runtimes, is it now okay to write shell extensions in managed code?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130222-01/?p=5163/)

So, okay fine I'll use C++ but the only examples of C++ shell extensions I can find just register a single context menu entry for a single file type which is too simple to satisfy my needs. I would like to be able to dynamically create the context menu entries based on the files selected as described in the top answer to this question: 
[WinRAR Context menu and file type detection of Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/555627/winrar-context-menu-and-file-type-detection-of-windows)

> You might want different menu items displayed based on whether one or multiple files have been selected. Since the number of files selected can be determined in IShellExtInit::Initialize, this becomes a trivial matter. You also have the ability to base the menu item on the file itself. In addition to the number of files selected, you would also already know the filenames in question. This means you could open the file, retrieve information, and base the menu item on actual data. Or you could examine some other attribute of the file (such as its creation date, its size, or its read-only status) and base the menu item on that information as well.

So in my search for how to do that, I find great code examples like this: [.NET Shell Extensions - Adding submenus to Shell Context Menus and Dynamically Loading Context Menu](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1035998/NET-Shell-Extensions-Adding-submenus-to-Shell-Con) that are written in .NET. And then I am back to square 1 trying to figure out if it is actually okay to use .NET to create shell extensions.

So, Questions:

If I follow the .NET shell extension tutorial I linked above, will my shell extension be slow, only work on certain windows operating systems (not worried about vista, but it would be great if it worked on all 7, 8, and 10 machines), or be dangerous? What if the target machine does not have the .NET framework installed? What if the target machine has an earlier version of the .NET framework installed?

Comment: I removed your second question as resource request are off topic.

Comment: I can only share a bit of my experiense. I once wrote shell extension for custom file synchronization application (like dropbox), which provided overlay icons, custom menus and so on, in .NET, and never received any complains that it was slow. Though anyway, I'd better listen to Raymond Chen than to myself.

Comment: You are injecting the CLR into Explorer and any program that uses the shell dialogs, like OpenFileDialog and friends.  So about all of them.  That is a very risky proposition, big boo-boo when that process already has the CLR loaded and it is not compatible with the one you want to inject.  Your extension won't work and you can't tell your user why and can't do anything about it.  And worse, you can break the app when it wants to load managed code later.  This isn't safe until CLR v2.0.50727 disappears.  Give it another decade or two.

Comment: You can use this commercial component: https://www.shellboost.com/ (disclaimer, I work for the vendor) that will allow you to develop a namespace extensions using .NET and follow Microsoft recommendations at the same time. It's possible because your .NET extension will be hosted out-of-process.

Comment: @SimonMourier impressive! :)